# Many to Many relationships with Laravel / Eloqeunt

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I think I understand Eloquent for the most part, but I still have some trouble understanding many to many relationships.

I'm designing a sample database, and hopefully you folks can help me out understand the right way to do it.

**Table 1:** categories

- `cat_id`
- `cat_name`

**Table 2:** galleries

- `gallery_id`
- `gallery_name`

**Table 3:** galleryCategories

- `cat_id`
- `gallery_id`

So how would I go about my models? I found this topic, but it didn't seem quite right. maybe because it's a bit more complex relationship than what I need. I think the logic confused me because I'd expect products to have terms whereas terms having products in that example.

If you could please explain it with my sample, it'll help me better understand the `belongsToMany()` and `hasMany()` methods and their parameters. I'm also confused with some examples not taking any foreign key parameters.

Thanks already!

Comment: What's the relationship between categories and galleries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work for your schema you need this:

```
// Category model
protected $primaryKey = 'cat_id';

public function galleries()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Gallery', 'galleryCategories', 'gallery_id', 'cat_id');
}

// Gallery model
protected $primaryKey = 'gallery_id';

public function categories()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Category', 'galleryCategories', 'cat_id', 'gallery_id');
}

// then:
$category = Category::first();
$category->galleries; // collection of Gallery models
```

---

To make it comply with Eloquent conventions, you would need:

```
// tables
categories: id, ...
galleries: id, ...
category_gallery: id, category_id, gallery_id [, timestamps]

// models
// Category
public function galleries()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Gallery');
}

// Gallery
public function categories()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Category');
}
```

The 2nd solution is way better if you want to make most of the framework, but if you want to rely on your schema, then you can make Eloquent adjust to it.

---

Note: `hasMany` is 1-m relation, `belongsTo` is its counterpart, while for many-to-many relationship with pivot table, you use `belongsToMany` on both ends.

Comment: Thanks this really clears things up for me! (PS: I think you made a typo with the Gallery model. the method name should be categories(), right?)